# Power BI: Custom Min/Max values into Visual (Line chart)

Tags: excel, powerbi, data-visualization, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to do some reporting stuff (engineering field), and I am stuck on some "simple" thing, how to insert/add custom Min/Max values so that I can have on the certain visual (like on the picture) border values, min and max that I have defined!

I am receiving set of data, where **Min/Max aren't included**, and I have to calculate them (those border values are defined by us). I tried to do **add column** but when I go to "analytics" and try to put there Min/Max, I am getting doubled lines and its quite messy (on pic below)... Is there any easier and better way to calculate / add that? From additional table or else??

Min would be 60 °C

Max would be 100 °C , it is just temperature range and its limitation.

[image]

So on the pic below, I tried Add Column into the Data and also Measure directly (60 and 100 degrees) and got this below....the problem is, you cant edit these lines... the thing is I wanted them from Analytics part but there I cant see them because they re not "existing".

[image]

Comment: what is that line around 25 degree celsius?

Comment: Thats is T02 temperature, usually I have T01 and T02 and that means if system is activated by certain inlet heating (T01 or T02) then one temperature goes over 60 degrees and another is around 20-30...but sometimes is not the case, if exceeds that then it is time for repair or service. 

I hope that is not big deal, but that actually will give/show 4 temperatures on this visuals...

Comment: ok.. have you tried with a measure of a constant value for ex: newmeasure= 60 and use it as a value?

Comment: wouldn't the "Constant line" from the analytics tab do exactly what you need? Wouldn't even need a new measure or column then

Comment: @hsan Hmmm good point actually...just tested seems OKAY, I guess this will work later, have to check on other examples where I got a bit more parameters, in a sense of "messy" visuals.  

But thx! I consider this helpful!

Comment: Oh, and if a measure or additional column suits your problem better and you still want to format a single line in a line chart you can enable the "Customize series" toggle for the set of options you want to change (e.g. look in the "Shapes" section).

Comment: @hsan Alright, both ways are good, depends what i actually wanna show and on ehich way...but this was helpful, I missed somehow those options here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after little bit of playing around and some suggests of PBI pros, I will just write two ways of getting the same results, with minor change.

1) You can insert measure/column into your data set (in my case that was Min = 60 and Max = 100), simple as a day. Then on **Format tab > Customize series** where you can adjsut your Line: width, type, style...

2) Without any calculation: On **Analytics tab > add 2x Constant Lines**, put values that you want and thats it.

The only difference here  is Data labeling, on 2nd option you can see your limiter value on one of the sides...and using 1st option, your limiter value is through whole line, and you cant remove it (for a whole line).  But depends what and how you wanna see your data.

Maybe there are some other ways but this one was fine for me, didnt explore fully PBI yet.